# sed replace literal TAB

Tags: sed, freebsd

I want to replace `TAB`s in `stdout` with semicolons, by running `sed` from the ZSH shell.

I understand one can normally (in other shells?) use:

```
somecommand | sed 's/\t/;/g'
```

However, this doesn't work for me in ZSH-shell under FreeBSD. **The `\t` doesn't match the tabulators. Why is this?** I've also tried multiple backslashes (up to 5).

---

This does work:

```
somecommand | sed 's/[TAB]/;/g'
```

, where `[TAB]` is an actual `TAB`-character, inserted by entering `Ctrl-V` followed by the `TAB` button on my keyboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use of zsh has nothing to do with it. The `\t` is a GNU extension to the regular expressions used in sed. On a BSD sed, you don't have the extensions, so have to use the literal tab.

Comment: @poplitea If your script will only run in ksh93, bash or zsh (as opposed to other sh variants such as pdksh, Bourne or ash), then you can use `$'s/\t/;/'g` where the shell does the backslash expansion and `sed` sees a literal tab character.

Comment: @Gilles: Fantastic! I knew of $(), but not of $'' substitution. Thank you very much, this makes it easy solving my problem. You should probably have put this in an answer rather than a comment, though(?).

Answer (score 3):

One option is to prepare your sed script ahead of time with printf.

```
scr="`printf 's/\t/;/g'`"
somecommand | sed "$scr"
```

But Michael++...  There may be other sed variants that also support printf-style escapes, but it's certainly not "standard".

Answer (score 0):

If you know the output of the command is normal text (only tabs & printable text), you could use:

```
somecommand | sed -E 's/[[:cntrl:]]/;/g'
```

`-E` turns on "extended" regular expressions, which can contain character class names.