# sed: convert time(3) seconds in a table into printable date (spamdb)

Tags: shell, sed, tcsh, openbsd

I get the following from [spamdb](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=spamdb&sektion=8), where the third field represents the time in seconds since the Epoch.

```
Cns# spamdb | fgrep TRAPPED
TRAPPED|113.163.117.129|1360836903
TRAPPED|113.171.216.201|1360837481
TRAPPED|122.177.159.61|1360844596
TRAPPED|36.231.9.231|1360865649
TRAPPED|37.146.207.209|1360832096
TRAPPED|212.156.98.210|1360837015
TRAPPED|59.99.160.62|1360839785
TRAPPED|86.127.116.162|1360840492
TRAPPED|92.83.139.194|1360843056
TRAPPED|219.71.12.150|1360844704
```

I want to sort this table by the time, and print the time field with `date -r`, such that it's presentable and clear when the event has occurred.

How do I do this in `tcsh` on OpenBSD?

Sorting with `sort` is easy, and so is editing with `sed`; but how do I make `sed` execute `date -r` or equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed a few obstacles here: first, you basically have to separate the data, and then one part of it is presented as-is, whereas another part has to be passed down to `date -r` for date formatting, prior to being presented to the user.

Another obstacle is making sure the output is aligned: apparently, it's quite difficult to handle the tab character in the shell, possibly only on the BSDs:

- [sed replace literal TAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400602/sed-replace-tab-in-zsh-shell)
- [Replacing / with TAB using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363328/replacing-with-tab-using-sed)

Also, as we end up piping this to `sh` for execution, we have to use a different separator for the fields other than the pipe character, `|`.

So far, this is the best snippet I could come up with, it seems to work great in my `tcsh`:

```
Cns# spamdb | fgrep TRAPPED | sort -n -t '|' -k 3 | sed -E -e 's#\|#@#g' \
    -e 's#^([A-Z]+)@([0-9.]+)@([0-9]+)$#"echo -n \2_"; "date -r \3"#g' | \
    xargs -n1 sh -c | awk '{gsub("_","\t",$0); print;}'
37.146.207.209  Thu Feb 14 00:54:56 PST 2013
113.163.117.129 Thu Feb 14 02:15:03 PST 2013
212.156.98.210  Thu Feb 14 02:16:55 PST 2013
113.171.216.201 Thu Feb 14 02:24:41 PST 2013
59.99.160.62    Thu Feb 14 03:03:05 PST 2013
86.127.116.162  Thu Feb 14 03:14:52 PST 2013
92.83.139.194   Thu Feb 14 03:57:36 PST 2013
122.177.159.61  Thu Feb 14 04:23:16 PST 2013
219.71.12.150   Thu Feb 14 04:25:04 PST 2013
36.231.9.231    Thu Feb 14 10:14:09 PST 2013
```